# Lat Lon Distance Calculation query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Oracle 11g DB. I store Latitude and Longitudes (for lets say stores or shops). Now i need a query which will calculate the distance between the shops and my location(which i will provide in the query). I have done this earlier in MySQL, but in Oracle there is no Radians function. So i need work aronud in Oracle SQL.

Help Appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

Create a function that converts degrees to radians:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION degree_to_radian(p_degree IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   RETURN p_degree / 57.2957795;
END degree_to_radian;
```

Answer (score 2):

or even more precise:

```
RETURN p_degree /(180/ACOS(-1));
```